# Подсказка вылезает за пределы экрана

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы подсказка не выходила за пределы экрана, то есть если ссылка находится в центре экрана, то все нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ссылка наверху (например название главы), то появляющаяся подсказка частично исчезает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`css`

```
<style>
        @media screen and (max-width: 412px){
            p{
            padding-right: 1px;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 413px){
            p{
            padding-right: 400px;
            }
        }
        nobr a{
            color: #6c0404
        }
        p{
            word-wrap: break-word;
            font-family: Open Sans,Tahoma,sans-serif!important;
            line-height: 1.4285em;
            box-sizing: inherit;
            display: block;
            margin-block-start: 1em;
            margin-block-end: 1em;
            margin-inline-start: 0px;
            margin-inline-end: 0px;
            font-size: 1.14285714rem;
            color: #120808;
        }
        .block {
            position: relative;
        }

        /* Оформление скрытого элемента по умолчанию */
        .hidden {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 130%;
            left: 0px;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #3aaeda;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        /* Появление скрытого элемента при клике */
        .focus:focus+.hidden {
            display: block;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
    }
    </style>
```

кусок `html`

```
<nobr class="block" title=""> <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="focus">Мэн Хао</a> <span class="hidden">Главный герой </span>
```

Comment: Может, лучше выводить снизу?

Comment: @fixer, тогда нижние строки будут уезжать вниз(